# Python regular expression to match and replace gradle dependencies output

Tags: python, regex, gradle, gradlew

I am super novice to regular expressions and Python, but want to achieve that.

I have this input:

```
\--- org.projectlombok:lombok:1.+ -> 1.16.6

+--- org.springframework:spring-aspects: -> 4.1.7.RELEASE
|    \--- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.6
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web: -> 1.2.6.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:1.2.6.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:1.2.6.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.7.RELEASE
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.1.7.RELEASE
```

Need to get a Python script, regular expression to remove "\" "-" "+" and space in the beginning of the line and replace word or space before "->" with the one after "->"

So the output should be:

```
org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.6
org.springframework:spring-aspects:4.1.7.RELEASE
org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.6
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.2.6.RELEASE
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:1.2.6.RELEASE
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:1.2.6.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.7.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-context:4.1.7.RELEASE
```

By the way This is output from gradlew dependencis for a project. Maybe there is a way to get this output from gradlew?

OK, this code does it in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re

with open('testfile') as infile, open('testout', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
      line = line.replace("\\","")
      line = line.replace("-","")
      line = line.replace(" ","")
      line = line.replace("+","")
      line = line.replace("|","")
      line = re.sub(r'(:[0-9.+]+)>', r':', line)
      line = re.sub(r':>', r':', line)
      outfile.write(line)
```

Output:

```
org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.6

org.springframework:springaspects:4.1.7.RELEASE
org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.6
org.springframework.boot:springbootstarterweb:1.2.6.RELEASE
org.springframework.boot:springbootstarter:1.2.6.RELEASE
org.springframework.boot:springboot:1.2.6.RELEASE
org.springframework:springcore:4.1.7.RELEASE
org.springframework:springcontext:4.1.7.RELEASE
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: [Should “Give me a regex that does X” questions be closed?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285733/should-give-me-a-regex-that-does-x-questions-be-closed/285739#285739)

Comment: Also, why don't you write a gradle task that will print out what you need?

Comment: Well, if you can point me to the resource that describe that I would be grateful. I need to get the list in the form as I mentioned in the output example (with version used, without "->" symbols). Please don't hate me :), I am just a beginner in this area, figured out this would be the great place to start my research

Comment: Have you thought about `line.lstrip(' -\+')`?

Comment: I updated my question with the latest version of Python code. It seem to be doing what I wanted. It is a ditry version :) Python experts, feel free to update it with clean and better version.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would want to use python for this when `gradle` is designed with dependency management built-in.  A simple gradle task could write the file for you.  The below would be executed by running `gradle writeDependencyFile`

```
task writeDependencyFile << {
    File output = new File("$project.rootDir.absolutePath/dependencies.txt")
    configurations.compile.each { File file ->
        output.append("${file.name.substring(0, file.name.lastIndexOf('.'))}\n")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you still need solution or not but today found regex pattern for that hope it will help.
`\w.*\S:\w.*`